# Lucene.net / c# / add filter query

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I am in doubt of how to make a query in lucene.net using BooleanQuery and TermQuery etc. I want it to act in the same way as this sql statement:

```
"... WHERE ((isprivate = false) OR (isprivate = true and userid = 1))"
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Untill now I only have

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
TermQuery isPrivateQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("isprivate", "true"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be rewritten as:

```
"... WHERE (isprivate = false) OR (userid = 1)"
```

So you can have the next code (considering that your values are stored as string):

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("isprivate", "true")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
booleanQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("userid", "1")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

If you want to make more complex queries, then you can add one BooleanQuery as a clause to another BooleanQuery:

```
// Creating "and" clause
BooleanQuery booleanQueryInner = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQueryInner.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("isprivate", "false")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQueryInner.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("userid", "1")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

// Creating "or" clause
BooleanQuery booleanQueryMain = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQueryMain.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("isprivate", "true")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
booleanQueryMain.Add(booleanQueryInner, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Comment: Could you help me out with the "clause" booleanquery as well ? Thanks in advance